# Upload files in storage directory in laravel can't write image to data path

Tags: laravel

I am trying to upload in laravel with intervention image plugin

But get this error. sorry 4 bad english

> Can't write image data to path
>   (E:\xampp\htdocs\my-project\storage\app/medicines/thumbs/medicines/MEmheIamxDfu8ePa1h5mtovKFzY0POJtfGW8BLYZ.jpeg)

```
  if($request->hasFile('photo')) { 

            $photo = $request->file('photo'); 

            $image = $photo->store('medicines'); 

            $path =  storage_path('app/') .$image ; 

            Image::make($path)->resize(75,75)->save(storage_path('app/medicines/thumbs/'.$image,50));
```

Comment: Just replace `/` with \ for windows ;)

Comment: where part ? what line ?

Comment: `storage_path('app/')` ==> `storage_path('app\')` and here `storage_path('app/medicines/thumbs/'.$image,50)` ==> `storage_path('app\medicines\thumbs\'.$image,50)`

Comment: Sorry replace it with double one  \\ !!

Comment: Is it working for you ??

Comment: it's not working for me..

Comment: What is the new error ?

Comment: Image source not readable

Comment: is it in the save or in the show ??

Answer (score 0):

- Error message mean that web server user have no permission to write in that path.

So to fix it:

1. Change your directory upload path to app/public or app/storage directory

   If you want to store in app/storage you can follow [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem)
2. Allow permission to web server(Apache user, etc.) to the path above